# Modifying a list should not affect its object - Java

Tags: java, list, immutability

I have a class Butterfly:

```
public class Butterfly extends Insect {

/**
 * Field to hold the list of colors that a butterfly object is.
 */
private List<String> colors;

/**
 * Constructor to initialize the fields.
 * 
 * @param species - Species of Butterfly.
 */
public Butterfly(String species, List<String> colors) {
    super(species);
    this.colors = colors;
}

/**
 * Constructor to initialize an existing Butterfly object.
 * 
 * @param butterfly - Butterfly object
 */
public Butterfly(Butterfly butterfly) {
    this(butterfly.getSpecies(), butterfly.getColors());
}

/**
 * Getter for the colors of the butterfly. 
 * 
 * @return the colors - Colors of the butterfly.
 */
public List<String> getColors() {
    return colors;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getSpecies() + " " + colors;
}

}
```

And a JUnit test case that is giving me issues:

```
@Test
void butterfly_immutable() {
    List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(colors, "orange", "black", "white");

    Butterfly b1 = new Butterfly("Monarch", colors);
    Butterfly b2 = new Butterfly(b1);

    // Modifying the original color list should not affect b1 or b2.
    colors.set(0, "pink");

    // Modifying the colors returned by the getters should not affect b1 or b2
    List<String> b1Colors = b1.getColors();
    b1Colors.set(1, "lime");
    List<String> b2Colors = b2.getColors();
    b2Colors.set(1, "cyan");

    assertTrue(sameColors(List.of("orange", "black", "white"), b1.getColors()));    
    assertTrue(sameColors(List.of("orange", "black", "white"), b2.getColors()));    
}
```

My question is: how do I prevent changing the colors of the Butterfly object if the colors themselves are modified. I have attempted using List.of, List.copyOf, Collections.unmodifiableList, and I just cannot seem to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Change the line

```
this.colors = colors;
```

to

```
this.colors = List.copyOf(colors);
```

This will make a the `Butterfly.colors` field an unmodifiable copy of the `List` passed into the constructor.

If you wanted `Butterfly` to be modifiable in other ways, you could make a mutable copy in the constructor, but you would also have to copy in the "getter".

```
this.colors = ArrayList<>(colors);

public List<String> getColors() {
    return List.copyOf(colors);
}
```

(Technically the `ArrayList` constructor can be defeated, but you shouldn't usually have to worry about that.)

Comment: I think I actually tried this at one point myself, but this gives me an "Unsupported Operation Exception" in my JUnit test case.

Comment: @BrandonBischoff Good! That properly shows you can't modify it. If you want the test, then it should catch the exception.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense; however I'm not allowed to change the JUnit test case from what it is. Also, I am not allowed to use ArrayList, only List, and I am unable to instantiate the type List in my return statement on my getter. This is why I've been so lost

Comment: @Brandon I'm also confused. Is this homework? If so, maybe ask your teacher why they gave requirements that can't be implemented due to the given restrictions.

Comment: Yes it's homework. All the assignments are created by the head of the department and our specific teachers only teach the information and grade assignments, which makes for less than ideal restrictions like this seemingly all the time.

Comment: @BrandonBischoff So bung a `new ArrayList<>()` into the getter together with a sarky comment.

Comment: Hahaha thank you again. I'll take it to my teacher and see what he has to say

Comment: @Brandon I'd be interested in the solution your teacher expects.

Answer (score 0):

Change getColors() method of Butterfly class:

```
public List<String> getColors() {
    return colors == null ? null : new ArrayList<>(colors);
}
```

Comment: This seems to only address "Modifying the colors returned by the getters should not affect b1 or b2", and not "Modifying the original color list should not affect b1 or b2.", and it's also very inefficient.